# Calculate LOC in perforce depot

Tags: perforce

Is it possible to get the total LOC for files in the depot?
I have already tried solutions which check for LOC's for changelists edited by a specific user using
    P4 describe -ds
    I wish to check the LOC for all the files under the directory without actually importing the files (Irrespective of the user who modified the file)
Also if this is possible wish to sort out these details with the file types.

Comment: You could use p4 print to get the file contents and do your analysis. Why not just sync the files and use a LOC tool on the workspace?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I can use the LOC tool in p4 for a single or couple of files but not a hundred files. :) which is why I wanted to do it using a program or command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a direct way to do this.  You can use p4 print, as someone else already suggested, or p4 sizes, which gives you the the size of a file revision in bytes (and you'd have to calculate the difference between subsequent revisions).

I recommend paying special attention to integrations.  If your Perforce server employs branches, you'll probably want to discount integrations from your metrics calculation.  Only the original change should get credit for adding/modifying lines, pushing that change to another codeline should not.

Comment: Exactly what I ended up doing or so I recall! got the results using p4 print